# jQuery using find or similar to search not children of array, but on the array using sizzle like notation

Tags: jquery

Given as an instance a returned value of something along like

```
function getSomething() {
   return element.find('> .something'); 
}
```

now, considering i can have multiple elements returned here, i might still want to filter these out quickly.

but I can not do:

```
getSomething().find('> .product')
```

for instance since it will search the children of the return value.

I can come up with this solution to iterate what I desire:

```
function getSomething() {
        var elements = element.find('> .something'); 
        elements.enclosed = function() {
              return jQuery('<div></div>').append(this.elements);
        }
        return elements; 
}
```

This will now allow me to do something along the lines `getSomething().enclosed().find('> .product')`

The question I have now, is wether there is already a **similar function** in the jQuery library ?

Note, I am aware I can extend jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it:

```
   elements.filter('.product')
```

Also this seems to work:

```
   elements.siblings('.product')
```

List of traversal methods found:

https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/